# Android Fragments - Google Maps v2 API + OpenGL ES 2 application runs slow

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, opengl-es

I have an app that displays two `fragments` inside the `MainActivity`: one `fragment` displays a simple `Google Map (API v2)` and the other one displays 2D stuff drawn using `OpenGL ES 2`. Both of these are quite simple things, not very resource consuming.

I currently tested the app only in the `Genymotion Emulator` and I noticed a severe framerate drop whenever I move the map around or zoom it. If I don't do anything, the framerate is quite good (20-30 fps). When I start moving the `map`, the framerate can drop all the way to 10.

I was wondering if I could use different threads for the `map` and/or `OpenGL` but I don't know how or if that is even possible. I'm not sure about the `map`, but I know that `OpenGL` already runs things in its own dedicated thread (or so I read over the internet).

Is there a way to further optimise what I am doing? Not necesarilly with threads. I didn't offer any code because both `fragments` work fine on their own and as I said they don't do much. I know I should also test my app on a real device but I currently don't have access to one and I am still curious if or how could I further optimise what I did.